# Django : FieldError at /editstu/121

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

Error :

Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: Age, Course_ID, DoB, Grade, Student_ID, Student_Name

[image]

My function in views.py

```
def Editstu(request,id):
    editstuobj = Student.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'editstu.html',{'Student':editstuobj})
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.showStudent),
    path('InsertStudent',views.InsertStudent,name="InsertStudent"),
    path('Insertcour',views.InsertCourse,name="InsertCourse"),
    path('editstu/<int:id>',views.Editstu,name="Editstu"),
    path('editcour/<int:id>',views.Editcour,name="Editcour"),
    # path('Update/<int:id>',views.updateemp,name="updateemp"),
    path('Deletestu/<int:id>',views.Deletestu,name="Deletestu"),
    path('Deletecourse/<int:id>',views.Deletecourse,name="Deletecourse"),
]
```

My Index.html

```
<td><a href="editstu/{{result.Student_ID}}">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="Deletestu/{{result.Student_ID}}" onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure to delete the record?')">Delete</a></td>
```

I checked the function if it is declared properly but no luck. I'm new to Django. It says error is 'id' but it should be fine. Please help if anyone can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the model field is `Student_ID` not `id` and also use [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) so:

```py
def Editstu(request,id):
    editstuobj = get_object_or_404(Student,Student_ID=id)
    return render(request, 'editstu.html',{'Student':editstuobj})
```

Also use `url tags` so:

```html
<td><a href="{% url 'Editstu' result.Student_ID %}">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="{% 'Deletestu' result.Student_ID %}" onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure to delete the record?')">Delete</a></td>
```